# Spring data mongodb serialization of InetSocketAddress

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

First off: I am very new to Spring, therefore I am sorry if I fail to provide all information necessary for the question. My problem is as follows: I have the following class which objects I want to save in a mongoDB

```
public class Subscription implements Serializable {

    private String type;
    private InetSocketAddress host;

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public InetSocketAddress getHost() {
        return host;
    }

    public void setHost(InetSocketAddress host) {
        this.host = host;
    }


    public Subscription(){}
```

I do this by just defining a Repository interface and autowiring it into my application (which works fine for another repository)

```
public interface SubscriptionRepository extends MongoRepository<Subscription, String> {
}
```

I can save Subscription objects into the repository, but reading them into a `List<Subscription>` via `SubscriptionRepository.findall()` gives me an error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [java.net.InetSocketAddress]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>()
```

Looking into the database the InetSocketAddress object is saved kind of weird

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e1a48f4a6e30c7d2089e5cd"), "type" : "test", "host" : { "holder" : { "addr" : { "holder" : { "address" : 174417169, "family" : 1 }, "_class" : "java.net.Inet4Address" }, "port" : 0 } }, "_class" : "com.example.myproject.Subscription" }
```

What do I have to change in order to save the InetSocketAddress field in a way so that I can retrieve the Subscription Object from the database correctly?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: You may extend `InetSocketAddress` class and define default constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InetSocketAddress is either a String host name or an InetAddress with an int port.

An InetAddress is basically an array of bytes.

Neither InetSocketAddress nor InetAddress can be used as java beans.

Instead of storing InetSocketAddress, store the String, byte[] and the port.  Better yet, convert the byte[] to a String representation of an IP address, and store just a String and a port, the String being either the host name or the IP address as a string.  Then add a method that constructs an InetSocketAddress whenever you need it.  Also add setters and getters for the port and the String host/address.

```
public class Subscription implements Serializable {

    private String type;

    // instead of InetSocketAddress
    private String host;
    private int port;

    public InetSocketAddress getSocketAddress() {
            return new InetSocketAddress(host, port);
    }

    // setters and getters
```